# My S3 generic function stops working after calling a print function in R

Tags: r, oop

I created a generic function and defined the class of the output within the function. I also created a print function that takes the output of the first function.

However, after I run print, the original function gives the output of print rather than the output I want it to give.

These are my methods:

```
fisher <- function(obj, ...){
  UseMethod("fisher")
}

fisher.default <- function(obj, ...){
  x<- -2*sum(log(obj))
  df <- 2*length(obj)
  p = pchisq(x, df,lower.tail = FALSE)
  class(p)="fisher"
  p
}

print.fisher <- function(print_obj){
  paste("The p-value of this vector is: ", print_obj)

}

xx= fisher(x)
```

`fisher` worked perfectly fine before creating and executing the `print.fisher` function. Now  `fisher(x)` gives the exact output as `print(xx)`.

What could possibly be going wrong?

Comment: you do not have a function called `fisher` defined in the question

Comment: `fisher<-function(obj, ...) UseMethod("fisher")`, like @rawr says.

Comment: I'm sorry i did not include the generic function in my question at first. Of course it was there in my code. Just edited my post.

Comment: Rewrite as `print(paste("The p-value of this vector is: ", print_obj))`.

Comment: `print(paste("The p-value of this vector is: ", print_obj))` did not work either.

Comment: I think @RuiBarradas answered your question, but two more comments on your version:  print methods need to be compatible with the generic, so the header should be `function(x, ...)` (though you can include more named args, the first needs to be `x`, and it needs to include `...`).  You should always print something, then return `x` invisibly.  Rui's works because `print()` does that, but it would not pass CRAN checks because he didn't rename the main argument.

Answer (score 0):

The following works with me. R 4.0.3 on Ubuntu 20.10.

```
fisher <- function(x, ...){
  UseMethod("fisher")
}

fisher.default <- function(x, ...){
  y <- -2*sum(log(x))
  df <- 2*length(x)
  p <- pchisq(y, df, lower.tail = FALSE)
  class(p) <- c("fisher", class(p))
  p
}

print.fisher <- function(x, ...){
  y <- paste("The p-value of this vector is:", unclass(x))
  print(y)
  invisible(y)
}

set.seed(2020)
x <- abs(rnorm(10))
xx <- fisher(x)
xx
#[1] "The p-value of this vector is: 0.985718045451049"
```

Running the function without assigning the output also calls the custom print method.

```
fisher(x)
#[1] "The p-value of this vector is: 0.985718045451049"
```

Comment: I tried your method and while 'print(xx)` displayed the result, `fisher(x)` did not display anything after running it. Shouldn't it display the value and the class? (excuse my mundane questions, I'm still new to R).